# JfreeChart: Stacked Bar Chart and CategoryAxis showing dates

Tags: charts, jfreechart, bar-chart

I have created a stacked bar chart in which I show a count on the *y* axis and dates on the *x* axis. The problem is that when I have many dates on the *x* axis it gets very cluttered and impossible to read. I would like to show only some of the dates, e.g one date per week. Is that possible? I am using `ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart()` to create the chart, and I have the data in a `DefaultCategoryDataSet`.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a [`CategoryAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#setCategoryLabelPositions%28org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions%29), which is used the for the domain axis in a `StackedBarChart`, you have considerable flexility with the method [`setCategoryLabelPositions()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#setCategoryLabelPositions%28org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions%29). Typical usage is illustrated in the [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) source, shown [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/3111/tree/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java).

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
    CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0));
```

Comment: Last seen [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/3111/tree/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the generateLabel methods in the label generator? Something like:

```
chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
  new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

    public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, Integer column) {
      if(column % 7 == 0)
        super.generateColumnLabel(dataset, column)
      else 
        ""
    }
  }
);
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should only output a label every 7 columns. More info on the label generator is here: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/CategoryItemLabelGenerator.html