# Display column keys of stacked bar chart vertically in jFreeCharts

Tags: jfreechart

I am developing a javaEE application using jfreecharts. I successfully displayed my data using a stackedBarChart but the column keys (Y-axis labels) are not fully displayed because they are too large. how can I display them vertically? thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setCategoryLabelPositions()` like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12178960/261156).

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I get an error, saying that the method createUpRotationLabelPositions needs a double as argument and   CategoryLabelPositions cannot be converted to a double. However I found a similar solution [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDualAxisDemo.htm). the only difference is that the method createUpRotationLabelPositions is not invoked. so it's simply                                CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);