# Setting a tick interval on a stackedareachart

Tags: java, jfreechart, stacked-area-chart

I have this chart produced by jfreechart's `stackedareachart`.  The label's on the x axis are the months of the year.  I need to be able to display every other label.  Something like:

```
Jan Mar Apr Jun Aug Oct Dec
```

[image]

I am able to do this when the Domain Axis is a `NumberAxis`, but I can't figure it out because the `stackedareachart` uses a CategoryAxis for the domain Axis.  CategoryAxis doesn't have a set tick mark interval method.

What can I do to display a subset of labels?

Comment: You might look a the approach suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12178960/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by using a `StackedXYAreaChart` instead of `StackedAreaChart`.  The advantage is the Domain Axis is a `NumberAxis`  It also had the benefit of not having those vertical lines running through the graph, so this solution pleased me.